# Replace last element string after looking the string in php

Tags: php, replace

How do I replace the last string after i have loop on each string?
I was able to do this but still not complete

```
// here my get string ?dir=hello1/hello2/hello3

if (isset($_GET['dir'])) {
    $hrefTabs = $_GET['dir']; 
    if (!empty($hrefTabs)) {
        $arrayOfhref = explode('/', $hrefTabs);//I explode string /

        foreach ($arrayOfhref as $roothrefline) {
            $trimstrhref = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $roothrefline); // Here i trim white space

            $mmhref = '<a href="'.$trimstrhref.'">'.$roothrefline.'</a> / '; // Here i assign each strin hyper reference

            $toreplace = $roothrefline . ' / ';
            $lastobj = substr_replace($mmhref, $toreplace, strlen($mmhref)); // here i want the last element not to have hyper reference attribut

            echo $lastobj; // but i get this at output 
            //<a href="">hello1</a> / hello1 / <a href="">hello2</a> / hello2 /<a href="">hello3</a> / hello3
        }
    }
}
```

My out put look like this

```
<a href="">hello1</a> / hello1 / <a href="">hello2</a> / hello2 /<a
href="">hello3</a> / hello3
```

I want to have it look like this

```
<a href="">hello1</a> / <a href="">hello2</a> / hello3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$dir = "hello1/hello2/hello3";

  if(isset($dir)){
     $hrefTabs = $dir;
     if(!empty($hrefTabs)){
    $arrayOfhref = explode('/', $hrefTabs);//I explode string /
    $i = 0;
    foreach($arrayOfhref as $roothrefline) {
      $trimstrhref = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $roothrefline); // Here i trim white space
      $mmhref = '<a href="'.$trimstrhref.'">'.$roothrefline.'</a> / '; // Here i assign each strin hyper reference
      $toreplace = $roothrefline . ' / ';

      if(++$i === count($arrayOfhref)){
        echo $roothrefline;
      } else {
        echo $mmhref;
      }
    }
  }
```

}

Something like this...

Answer (score 2):

Before your foreach do

```
$lastElement = array_pop($arrayOfHref);
```

and display $lastElement just after your loop.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php

Comment: can you please update the full code more better for others to understand i got this error `Warning: array_pop() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in`

Comment: @StuartBrian Hey, it's your code, just try to implement it, if you'll succeed, you can always edit your question. The goal of stackoverflow is not to code for someone, but to help one diagnose a problem and find solution. Check if your array is declared before you call array_pop, because it seems that it's not

Comment: i i could fix that no need to ask for solution, i just need help on that i have tried everything i could

Comment: @StuartBrian paste your new code on pastebin and put the link in comment, I can take a look. http://pastebin.com/

Comment: `$arrayOfhref` and `$arrayOfHref` are different vars. Please learn php more carefully.

Comment: @StuartBrian first of all, you've got typos in your code, you're using `$arrayOfHref` (uppercase H) and `$arrayOfhref` (lowercase h). PHP is case-sensitive, so it treats those as two separate variables. Also you didn't use `$lastElement` after your loop.

Comment: @StuartBrian: I'm having a good mood today, here's your solution. But please examine it carefully and try to find where you made your mistakes - treat it like educational material:

http://pastebin.com/8CJpjGyv